# General error: 1364 Field 'el' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php

How to solve this,

My table structure was look like below

> CREATE TABLE `leave_histroy` (   `his_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT
>   'histroy id auto increment',   `user_id` int(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'get
>   from users table id',   `cl` double(4,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'casual
>   leave',   `sl` double(4,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'seak leave',   `el`
>   double(4,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'earned leave',   `mt` double(4,2) NOT
>   NULL COMMENT 'maternity leave',   `pt` double(4,2) NOT NULL COMMENT
>   'paternity leave',   `lop` double(4,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'loss of pay',
>   `compoff` double(4,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'compensatory off leave',
>   `year` year(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'store leave year',   `created_on`
>   date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'created time',   `created_by` varchar(100)
>   NOT NULL COMMENT 'created by whome?',   `updated_on` date DEFAULT NULL
>   COMMENT 'updated time',   `updated_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT
>   'updated by whom?' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-insert function -

```
$query = "INSERT
    INTO
        `leave_histroy`(
            `user_id`,
            `cl`,
            `sl`,
            `year`,
            `created_by`
        )
    VALUES(
        :create_by,
        :casual_leave,
        :sick_leave,
        :year,
        :create_by
    )";
try {
    $result = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    $result->bindParam(":create_by", $leave_param['create_by']);
    $result->bindParam(":casual_leave", $leave_param['casual_leave']);
    $result->bindParam(":sick_leave", $leave_param['sick_leave']);
    $result->bindParam(":year", $leave_param['year']);
    $result->bindParam(":create_by", $leave_param['create_by']);
    $result->execute();
    return $result;
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try after ALTER TABLE `leave_histroy` CHANGE `el` `el` DOUBLE(4,2) NULL COMMENT 'earned leave';         Also set the defualt value for other columns if you are not inserting data.

Comment: Problem is in your Prepared statement. because i checked and try to insert this it works fine. Look here https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: already his_id is primary key

Comment: @KumarPraveen i done default value in leave_histroy but i received error from another table, error is :    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'emp_code' cannot be null

Comment: @kalaivanan can you show me the structure of your second table

Comment: @KumarPraveen thanks for replay i solved my problem

Comment: @kalaivanan thats great

Answer (score 0):

Change your Prepared Statement to this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `leave_histroy`( `user_id`, `cl`, `sl`, `year`, `created_by`) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
$query->bind_param("iiiis", $create_by, $casual_leave, $sick_leave, $year, $create_by);
    try {
        // set parameters and execute
        $create_by =  $leave_param['create_by']
        $casual_leave = $leave_param['casual_leave']
        $sick_leave = $leave_param['sick_leave']
        $year = $leave_param['year']
        $create_by = $leave_param['create_by']
        //Execute Statement
        $stmt->execute();
        //return $result;
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
       die();
       return false;
    }
```